# Which type of field should I take for likes model in django, Foreign key or ManyToManyField

Tags: django, database, model, relationship

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Or

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    picture = models.ManyToManyField(Picture)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And please explain why in either case

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using a `ForeignKey` means that each `Like` instance points to one user and one picture. Using `ManyToMany` means that each `Like` instance points to many users, and many pictures. Generally speaking, if you are creating a new model to store likes it makes more sense to use foreignkeys, where you are storing a new `Like` for each picture a user likes. You can refer to the documentation to learn more about how they work [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

Comment: But I'm confused because many users can like many picture and many pictures can be liked by many users

Comment: If you were to choose whould you choose to make separate model for likes or add a like coloum (ManyToMany) in pictures table and why?

Comment: If you choose the `ManyToMany` on the user approach, behind the scenes it'll create a new model. The first approach is just doing it explicitly. So it's up to you, it would depend on how you want to interact with your data. Querying `Like` directly or having to always go through the user.

Comment: I recommend the ForeignKey approach, we implemented something similar to that, it works very well and is scalable ( > 20 million objects). fyi m2m works different to how you think it works. It actually creates an additional Table to represent the connection so your Like Model with the two m2m Fields would create two more Tables representing something different. If you want to use m2m you'd have to add a liked_pictures Field to the User and a reverse relation to the Picture. The docs explain this quite good https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/